# how can i compare my textbox value to my database using ASP.net

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I am trying to make a login page,for this on the login page the text box value should be same as in my database,how to apply the logic for this ,using the ASP.net

Comment: You have a lot to learn man! start from here: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security

Answer (score 0):

You have to be a bit more specific as to what it is you're wanting, how you retrieve data from the database, and so on.
Basically, after retrieving the field from the database, do a comparison. Something like this...
Suppose the textbox is called txtUsername and the field in the database table is username, you'd do something like

```
if (txtUsername.text == db.username)
{
// Do something
}
```

Hope this helps. Otherwise, more details is needed to answer the question correctly.

Comment: I don't have a database concept in ASP.net
can you give me any book or link from where I can clear my concept about how to insert or print data from my database in ASP.net